# Angular Material Design $mdDialog.prompt is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Why is my `$mdDialog.prompt` is not working, whereas `$mdDialog.confirm` is working fine for me?

The code I have used is:

```
$scope.showPrompt = function(ev) {
    var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
        .title('What would you name your dog?')
        .textContent('Bowser is a common name.')
        .placeholder('dog name')
        .ariaLabel('Dog name')
        .ok('Okay!')
        .cancel('I\'m a cat person');

    $mdDialog.show(confirm);
}
```

During this I am getting error in console as `TypeError: $mdDialog.prompt is not a function`
But if I use the below code it is working fine:

```
$scope.showPrompt = function(event) {
    var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
        .title('Are you sure to delete the record?')
        .textContent('Record will be deleted permanently.')
        .ariaLabel('TutorialsPoint.com')
        .targetEvent(event)
        .ok('Yes')
        .cancel('No');
    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
        $scope.status = 'Record deleted successfully!';
    }, function() {
        $scope.status = 'You decided to keep your record.';
    });
};
```

Comment: which version you are using, because `.prompt` is only available from v1.1.0rc1 and above.

Comment: I am using version 1.3.15 so is there any other way to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The `$mdDialog.prompt()` is only available in `v1.1.0rc1`.

[Here](http://codepen.io/DevVersion/pen/aNZXoY) is the working example and [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7535) is the GitHub issue

Please check the version and use the available function accordingly.

Thanks.

Comment: The best solution to use it is by the way i am using 1.3.15

Comment: @RamanaUday It is your Angular Material Version or Angular version?

Comment: sorry material version is 1.0.0 and angular version is 1.3.15